# Prove that if $f$ is a bounded function on $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(ax)=bf(x)$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=f(0)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Prove that if $f$ is a bounded function on $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(ax)=bf(x)$ for $0\le x \le \frac{1}{a}$ and $a,b>1$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=f(0)$.

What about using the epsilon delta definition ?

$|f(x)-f(0)|< \epsilon$ I am literally stuck here can anyone show the steps?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Let $a=2=b$.
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(ax)=b\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$.

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=0 \space \text{or} \space \pm\infty$.

Can you go from there ?

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x = 0$ we get $f(0) = bf(0)$ so that $f(0) = 0$. Moreover note that $$f(1) = f(a\cdot1/a) = bf(1/a) = b^{2}f(1/a^{2}) = \cdots = b^{n}f(1/a^{n})$$ and hence $$f(1/a^{n}) = \frac{f(1)}{b^{n}}$$ From this it follows that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(1/a^{n}) = 0 = f(0)$$ Also note that $1/a^{n} \to 0$ and hence if $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x)$ exists it must be equal to $f(0)$. But we still need to show that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x)$ exists.